# How to get 'TFS get' command to not ignore itemspec and workspacename combination

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

In my setup, I am getting some code from client TFS site which I am accessing through a special machine in my company. There is no chance of us getting our machine on the client domain.

I have created two local workspaces, Automation and Manual, with same TFS user id.

> Automation ($/AllCode/AppProject, D:\WorkspaceAutomation)
>
> Manual ($/AllCode, D:\Worspace)

This user id is also registered with windows credentials store. Automation is to be used with a script while Manual with VS 2013 as backup.

When I give command like below, code gets synced to Manual folder D:\Workspace rather than to D:\WorkspaceAutomation

> [TFS get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) $/AllCode/AppProject /version:WAutomation /recursive /noprompt /login:username,password

When I give command like below, code gets synced to Automation folder D:\WorkspaceAutomation correctly.

> [TFS get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) D:\WorkspaceAutomation /version:WAutomation /recursive /noprompt /login:username,password

Is there a way to make earlier command work and not provide local path as itemspec? Going with later means some changes to my script which I am looking to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The server itemspec argument is like `$/SiteApp/Main/SolutionA`, which specifies a path to a folder on your Team Foundation Server, so try `$/AllCode/AppProject`, not `$\AllCode\AppProject`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have updated the question. I am using '$/AllCode/AppProject' only.

Comment: Where did you run tf get command? In your case, you need to go to workspace Automation to run tf get command, then your code will sync to workspace Automation.